# How to handle rejection when you really want to get in and they won't reconsider you?

Tags: rejection

Just interviewed in one of the coolest startups, and it might be one of a kind. It's software, so I had to go through 3 code challenges. Verdict came, and I wasn't able to perform at a level they'll accept.

From what I've heard they won't consider any reapplication within a year of this rejection.

I think I have the skills and experience to be there.

What should I do?

Try to find some company that touches the same problems where I could grow more, and reapply someday with more experience (but might still be rejected because code challenges are not really day-to-day in any company)?

Comment: Being good enough isn't enough though. You have to be the best candidate of all the ones that apply. If they're as hot of a startup as you say, I bet there's a lot of people applying.

Comment: "I think I have the skills and experience to be there". They think you do not have them, or do not fit their team.

Comment: @SalvadorDali or that someone better applied.

Comment: Don't feel bad, competition for software jobs is cutthroat.  Acing the interview (or several rounds of technical interviews, which seems to be the case these days) used to guarantee an offer -- this is no longer true.  I can only conclude that there is an oversupply of great software engineers at the moment (at least in some markets).

Comment: Consider this: If they "reconsider" you, that means there is another guy who was offered the job and now gets the door slammed into his face. "Sorry, we thought you were the right one for the job but we changed our mind". Not very professional.

Answer (score 37):

What you don't seem to be understanding is that while the job seemed perfect to you, you did not seem perfect to them. Other people did a better job than you did and thus were selected. Hiring is a competition, you did not place first.

Since word is you need to wait a year, then that is what you do. You don't bug them every two weeks in the meantime either. You spend a year getting more proficient at the type of programming they do. You spend the year practicing coding tests so that you can do better on them and you spend the year making network contacts in various user groups in the hope that you will connect with some of their employees who will get to know you through your work in helping set up the XYZ conference.

In the meantime, stop mooning over what might have been. That ship has sailed. Get a different job and give it your all.

Comment: Could not agree more. But its tough to know that by practicing code challenges I'd be putting even more effort in the hope I'd be considered.

Comment: They won't be the only company that uses coding tests

Comment: Definitely, it's worthwhile looking at the interview questions on Glassdoor to better prepare ahead of time.  A lot of times for companies like Google, Microsoft, Amazon, you might need to prepare for over 6 months.

Comment: Also read [this mostly fascinating book](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B009RQGW64/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?ie=UTF8&btkr=1).  I hate the title, it should really be called "Understanding the hiring interview model".

Answer (score 7):

Instead of crying after a company that doesn't want you, seriously focus on finding one that wants you. There are plenty of companies out there. If one doesn't want you, that's normal - consider that they wanted to hire one person, and if ten applied, then nine get rejected. That's why you apply at ten places, so for one of them you are the one.

One thing: You don't practice for code challenges. You write code and get good at it. Once you are good enough, there are no code "challenges" any more.

Answer (score 0):

At the rejection phase, it honestly never hurts to ask, "I really want this job and would like to prove it. What can I do to prove I am capable?"

In any event, never think that you're not good enough for someone else. Instead, always think it is their loss that they could not have you. Otherwise I'm not really sure how to answer this question. It's more of opinion rather than hard, actionable items.

Comment: Actually, it may hurt. Next year they'll say "remember that weirdo who wouldn't let go and begged as for the job three every two weeks? He's back..."

Comment: "never think that you're not good enough for someone else" - I disagree. If I applied for a job as a brain surgeon, I am simply not good enough. If I actually want to be a brain surgeon, I've got to go and put in some hard graft to learn some new skills. If I just think around thinking "I'm good enough, it's their loss", I'm never going to achieve my goal because I won't be motivated to get better.